# Check if parent div have height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a directive using nano-scroller, that should have some fixed height.
The structure is like this :

```
<div id="parent_div">
  <my-custom-directive>
        <div>...</div>
        <div id="div_required_to_have_fixed_height">...</div>
  </my-custom-directive>
</div>
```

I want to have some fix height at div with id-**div_required_to_have_fixed_height** . The style height parameter can be provided at the first div with id -**parent_div**.
So at div **div_required_to_have_fixed_height**, I want to check if height present at parent level, then use that otherwise use *height:500px*

Is there anyway to achieve this using angular/css.

Comment: You can get the parents heigth of the selected fixed-height-div using jQuery `$('#div_required_to_have_fixed_height').closest('#parent_div').css('height')`

Comment: Can't use this as in my custom directive there is no information for parent div id

Answer (score 0):

You might find offsetHeight useful:

```
var element = document.getElementbyId("div_required_to_have_fixed_height");
var height = element.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: I don't know why but this is giving error - element.offsetHeight() is not a function

Comment: My bad, it is a property, not a function. Should have checked. use offsetHeight.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you're looking for, I would recommend trying the [min-height](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) css attribute.

In your case `min-height:500px;`

At which point, you can add an event listener on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) to determine if the height require's adjusting.

Something like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
   //here you can invoke a function to check the parent div
});
```